# What is the probability that you pick 3 green, no red, 1 of each, at least 1 blue marble if a jar contains 5 blue, 3 green, and 4 red marbles.

Tags: probability

> A jar contains $5$ blue, $3$ green, and $4$ red marbles.  If you pull out three of these marbles at random, what is the probability that you have pulled:
>
> a) $3$ green marbles?
>
> b) $0$ red marbles?
>
> c) $1$ marble of each color?
>
> d) at least $1$ blue marble?

For the first part I got, $\frac3{12} = \frac14 = 0.25 = 25\%$
But I am not sure if it is correct and how to do the rest correctly.

Comment: The probability that the first picked marble is green equals $\frac3{12}$, but you are asked to give the probability that *all* $3$ marbles that are picked out are green.

Comment: Oh okay, but how would I go about solving it? I don't know how

Comment: For $i=1,2,3$ let $G_i$ denote the event that the $i$-th marble that is picked is green. Then be found is:$$P(G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3)=P(G_1)P(G_2\mid G_1)P(G_3\mid G_1\cap G_2)$$Can you find these probabilities on RHS? I preassume that the marbles are not placed back after being picked. For b) you can use the same principle but then for marbles that are not red. Then for d) again use the same principle for finding the probability of $0$ blue marbles (the complement). c) is the most problematic question I think.

Answer (score 1):

For a),b),d) see my comment.

c)

The probability that first we pick according to order (blue,green,red) equals:$$\frac5{12}\frac3{11}\frac4{10}$$

However there are other orders possible. So for each of them find the probability of occuring and take the summation of these probabilities.